# Why are all indices in an array 0?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Why does the following code output `0` indices?

I want the indices to be: `0 1 2 3 4 ...`. How do I fix it?

**Code:**

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
    foreach($data as $datum){
        $newArray = array_chunk($datum['units'], 3);
        foreach($newArray as $newA){
            $output = array(implode(",",$newA));
            echo print_r($output).'<br>'; //this is output
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 ) 1
>  Array ( [0] => khobe,22,22 ) 1
>   Array ( [0] => salam,55,55 ) 1
>  Array ( [0] => khobe,66,66 ) 1

I want this output:

> Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 ) 1
>  Array ( [1] => khobe,22,22 ) 1
>   Array ( [2] => salam,55,55 ) 1
>  Array ( [3] => khobe,66,66 ) 1

**Update:**

My JSON encoded in the database:

```
[{
    "units": ["salam", "11", "11", "khobe", "22", "22"],
}, {
    "units": ["salam", "55", "55", "khobe", "66", "66"],
}]
```

Comment: Debate rages on about whether 0 or 1 is the best starting index for arrays. My suggestion of 0.5 was dismissed without, I felt, proper consideration.

Comment: change this line: `$output = explode(",",$newA));`

Comment: What did you want the indexes to be?

Comment: I'm not following. Do you need a single array containing all rows or different arrays, each starting at a different index?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't put `echo` in front of `print_r`.

Comment: To be honest, I think you need to go back to basics. It sounds like you don't understand what is going on within your own code. Asking further questions that you should be able to debug yourself just makes you and us more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third foreach, you need to add the $output to a new array, then print_r after the loop.

E.g.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
        foreach($data as $datum){
        $newArray = array_chunk($datum['units'], 3);
        $count = 0;
        foreach($newArray as $newA){
            $output = array($count =>implode(",",$newA));
            $count++;
            print_r($output).'<br>'; //this is output
        }

        }
    }
```

Or similar.
You might need to move the $count = 0;

Comment: this code output is this: `Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 ) 1
Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 [2] => salam,55,55 [3] => khobe,66,66 ) 1`

Comment: You're just wanting the last set?

Comment: Move the print_r to the bottom of the snippet.

Comment: I /think/ that might be what you're asking for (not tested). Although I can't imagine why you want that. (See updated answer)

Comment: `Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 ) Array ( [1] => khobe,22,22 ) Array ( [0] => salam,55,55 ) Array ( [1] => khobe,66,66 )` Please see to my json encode in update post.

Answer (score 1):

On this line `$output = array(implode(",",$newA));` you are creating a new array for each set of results, so the offset with always start at 0.

Try this:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
    foreach($data as $unit) {
        $output[] = implode(',', $unit['units']);
    }
}
```

print_r($output);

I get the following output from a single row:

```
Array
(
    [0] => salam,11,11,khobe,22,22
    [1] => salam,55,55,khobe,66,66
)
```

Comment: output your code is thie: `Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 ) Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 ) Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 [2] => salam,55,55 ) Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 [2] => salam,55,55 [3] => khobe,66,66 )`

Comment: Can you show what one of the json strings looks like?  And what do you want your final output to be?  I think you may not need the `foreach($data as $datum)` or the array_chunk parts depending on what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$output[] = array(implode(",",$newA));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using a standard for loop like this instead of the foreach loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($newArray); $i++) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i change as: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($newArray); $i++) {
       $output = array(implode(",",$newA));
       echo print_r($output).'<br>';
   }` it have error: `Message: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed` & `Undefined variable: newA`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating all separate arrays every time you call the `array` function. To add items to the same array, use `$output[] = $valueToAdd`:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
    foreach($data as $datum){
        $newArray = array_chunk($datum['units'], 3);
        foreach($newArray as $newA){
            $output[] = implode(",",$newA);
        }
    }
}
print_r($output).'<br>'; //this is output
```

Comment: your code output: `Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 ) 1
Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 ) 1
Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 [2] => salam,55,55 ) 1
Array ( [0] => salam,11,11 [1] => khobe,22,22 [2] => salam,55,55 [3] => khobe,66,66 ) 1`

Comment: Yes, indeed. The `echo` should have been outside the loop. The loop is ok, and the arrat is created ok too, but everytime a value was pushed onto the array, the entire array was echoed again.

Comment: And `print_r` echos itself. The echo in front of it is unnecessary.